# Labels are overlapping at scale 25 Mio. in QGIS?

Tags: labeling, qgis-2

when I zoom-out (at a scale 25 Mio.), the labels are overlapped and it **shouldn't be** overlapping like the image below (in red drawn 'circle'),

Is it because of the size of the labels or do I have to move the 'elevation' (= Kinabalu 4101 and Raya 2278') manually?

[image]

Comment: Hard to say..., but is it possible one of your overlapping layers has a label setting to be fixed relative to the point? Older labeling system could place labels this way, such as upper right or upper left. If is is the case, older labels (cannot move easily) can overlap with new labels. To know your label settings, please check which of the `Labels` or `Labels (deprecated)`  is active on your Layer Properties.

Comment: @Kazuhito yes, in placement > around point is checked > Quadrant is 0 (above left). so what you meant is that I shouldn't set them like this, so ill remove them manually?

Comment: If your project had two labeling system and they were conflicting, deactivating one of them may improve the situation. Probably it will require some trials to find a workable combination.